# Get VLAN tag or untag via SNMP on Procurve Switch

Tags: linux, networking, snmp, net-snmp

How can I get via SNMP if the VLAN where a port belongs is tagged or untagged on a Procurve switch ?

I've found with this OID : `.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.4.3.1.4` that it returns a series of hex code that should tell me which port belongs to a vlan (this is an extract for vlan 1 and 100):

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public 192.168.0.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.4.3.1.4
```

SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.7.1.4.3.1.4.1 = Hex-STRING: 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 
00 03 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 80 00 00 00

SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.7.1.4.3.1.4.100 = Hex-STRING: FF FF FF FF E0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
03 F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

My questions are:

1. How can I get the ifindex from this HEX code?
2. How can I understand it the port is tagged or untagged?
   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.4.3.1.4` is dot1qVlanStaticUntaggedPorts, part of dot1qVlanStaticTable, defined in Q-BRIDGE-MIB. If a port is listed by this object, it is untagged. If a port is listed in dot1qVlanStaticEgressPorts, also part of dot1qVlanStaticTable, but *not* listed in dot1qVlanStaticUntaggedPorts, then it is tagged.

Both dot1qVlanStaticEgressPorts and dot1qVlanStaticUntaggedPorts are of type PortList, also defined in Q-BRIDGE-MIB. Each bit of each octet corresponds to one ifIndex, with the most significant bit of the first octet being ifIndex=1, the next bit being ifIndex=2, and so on. If the bit is 1, it is a member; if it is 0 then it is not.

Strange that the agent would be returning such long values (= many, many, **many** ports), though.